# Asp.net mvc dropdownlist cascading error Cannot set property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

Hy.
I want to make dropdownlist cascadin. select dropdownlist and send editorfor.but
Cannot set property 'value' of null error .
I would like to send a value to editorfor a value of dropdownlist.
Can you help me?

```
   public JsonResult GetPrice(string log)
        {
            int id = 1;
            HomeController.sqlconnection con = new HomeController.sqlconnection();
            string FIRMA = "select t.FIRMA,t.donem FROM dbo.TBLFRM as t where t.ID=" + id + "";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(FIRMA, con.connect());
            SqlDataReader rdrr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            rdrr.Read();
            string firma = rdrr["FIRMA"].ToString();
            string donem = rdrr["DONEM"].ToString();
            ExtreModel item = new ExtreModel();
            item.ItemList = new List<ExtreModel>();
            string urun = "select P.PRICE from DBO.LG_" + firma + "_PRCLIST as p,DBO.LG_" + firma + "_ITEMS as I WHERE P.CARDREF=I.LOGICALREF AND P.CARDREF=" + log + "";

            SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand(urun, con.connect());            
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmdd.ExecuteReader();
            rdr.Read();
                   string PRICE = rdr[0].ToString();
                con.connect().Close();
                return Json(PRICE, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }



 <script>
        $("#LOGI").change(function () {
            var select = $(this);
            var cityname = select.val();
            if (cityname != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: '/Mobil/GetPrice' + '?log=' + cityname,
                    beforeSend: function () {

                    }
                }).done(function (result) {
                    document.getElementById("fyt").value = result.PRICE;
                });
            } else {
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: My 2 cents went to this line which causing problem: `document.getElementById("fyt").value = result.PRICE;`. What element which has `id="fyt"` and why not just using `$('#fyt').val(result)`?

Comment: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PRICE, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "price", @class = "form-control" } })

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Does the error occur in the browser itself or is it thrown by the server already?

Comment: yes.return [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems coming from this `return` statement:

```
return Json(PRICE, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This statement returns plain string value which doesn't contain `PRICE` property, so `result.PRICE` contains null value and causing null property assignment error message. If you want to return the price value, simply use this inside `done` function:

```
document.getElementById("fyt").value = result;
```

or in jQuery version:

```
$('#fyt').val(result);
```

But if you still want to return `PRICE` property, specify it inside JSON data:

```
return Json(new { PRICE = PRICE }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And the AJAX callback should be look like this:

```
$("#LOGI").change(function () {
    var cityname = $(this).val();
    if (cityname != "") {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Mobil/GetPrice',
            data: { log: cityname }
            }).done(function (result) {
                $("#fyt").val(result.PRICE); // now the price property should exist
            });
    } else {
       // do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: Tetsuya Yamamoto , I make your say but I select in dropdownlist and send  [object Object] at editorfor

Comment: Are you mean `result.PRICE` returns `[object Object]` array? Sounds like it returns JSON object, you can check with `console.log(result)` and see what kind of object is returned.